# Fix Study Error: Loop takes too long to execute

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, trading

I'm trying to build a strategy that buys when the First bar closes by at least 10.00 higher than its open. If the Second bar closes below the close of the First bar, then it sells. But otherwise it stays in. If the Third bar closes above the close of the Second bar, then it stays in. But otherwise it sells. What am I doing wrong that I keep getting the error on the chart of "Study Error  Error on bar 18349: Loop takes too long to execute (> 500ms)"

```
//@version=5

strategy("SecretSauce",
     overlay=true, 
     initial_capital=100000,
     default_qty_type=strategy.percent_of_equity, 
     default_qty_value=100, // 100% of balance invested on each trade
     commission_type=strategy.commission.cash_per_contract, 
     commission_value=0.000) // commissions rate)

// Get user input
//i_stopPercent   = input.float(title="Stop Loss Percent", defval=0.10, step=0.1, group="Strategy Parameters", tooltip="Failsafe Stop Loss Percent Decline")
i_startTime     = input.time(title="Start Filter", defval=timestamp("01 Jan 1999 13:30 +0000"), group="Time Filter", tooltip="Start date & time to begin searching for setups")
i_endTime       = input.time(title="End Filter", defval=timestamp("01 Jan 2099 19:30 +0000"), group="Time Filter", tooltip="End date & time to stop searching for setups")

// Check filter(s)
f_dateFilter = (time >= i_startTime) and (time <= i_endTime)

// Check buy/sell conditions
var float buyPrice = 0.00
var float current_range = 10.00
buyCondition = (close > (open + current_range)) and (strategy.position_size == 0) and f_dateFilter
sellCondition = (close < buyPrice) and (strategy.position_size > 0)
//stopDistance = strategy.position_size > 0 ? ((buyPrice - close) / close) : na
//stopPrice = strategy.position_size > 0 ? buyPrice - (buyPrice * i_stopPercent) : na
//stopCondition = strategy.position_size > 0 and stopDistance > i_stopPercent

// Enter positions
if buyCondition
    strategy.entry(id="Long", direction=strategy.long)
    //atr := high - low
    current_range := close - open
    buyPrice := close

while strategy.position_size > 0
    if close < buyPrice
        strategy.close(id="Long", comment="Exit; SL=true")

    else if close >= buyPrice
        buyPrice := close
```

I've tried changing the date range ("i_startTime") so that it only processes a portion of the whole data set but that didn't work.

Comment: `while strategy.position_size > 0` this is an infinite loop as long as you are in a long position. Did you mean to do `if strategy.position_size > 0`?

Comment: ^^ I did. The first conditional statement:

 "    if close < buyPrice
        strategy.close(id="Long", comment="Exit; SL=true")"

Is supposed to exit the loop by making the position_size = 0.

Answer (score 0):

There are some problems and I trying to clear them for you:

1- var float current_range = 10.00
You just wanted a constant value so:
current_range = 10.0 is enough

2- buyCondition = (close > (open + current_range))
this condition is related to the current live candle, not 2 & 3 candles before
this condition passed for all green candles and strategy cannot trig for a million green candles

3- while strategy.position_size > 0
In Pine script, you don't need to add a while loop to build a backtest strategy
you should write like this:

```
if close_condition == true
    strategy.close(id="Long", comment="Exit; SL=true")
```

4- (strategy.position_size == 0)
you can add Pyramiding_factor = 1 in the Strategy initial setting and remove this condition from your code

5- Finally, in terms of sell conditions:

```
primary_sell_Cond = close[3] > open[3] + 10.0
secondary_sell_Cond = close[2] < close[3] ? true : (close[1] < close[2] ? : true: false)
final_sell_condition = primary_sell_Cond and secondary_sell_Cond
```

6- Pine Script is not a programming language such as Python, there are many differences, It's important to know that: your Pine-Script code executes after any new candle, something like an internal hidden loop from the available first candle and current live candle.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to help me with this. I do really appreciate it!

1. I updated the value to just 10.0

2. I understand what you are saying now but this is why I used the conditional  statement of "strategy.position_size == 0" so that it wouldn't trigger for a million green candles

3. I used a "while" loop because I wanted to in the future adjust it so that green bars after the Second would have to have a trading range (close - open) of a dynamically changing value. For example, say the Third bar is 50 wide, I want the Fourth bar to be at least 51 wide else I would sell.

Comment: For 4. I'm not sure what you are saying here. I don't want to pyramid in to this strategy.

For 5. It only needs to be higher than the previous bar.